# Как вывести сообщение или диалог на рабочий стол из приложения на android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

И снова всем привет. Где можно почитать о том как можно выводить сообщения или любую другую информацию на рабочий стол телефона и другие любые доступные места из своего приложения android? Одна из частей моего проекта - планировщик задач и я хочу что бы за 2 часа до события человеку вывешивалось оповещение на рабочем столе. В общем, где и что почитать ?

Comment: [Notifications](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/509-android-notifications-osnovy.html)

Comment: Я имел в виду такой механизм,что бы на рабочем столе телефона что-то висело из приложения(сообщение-напоминание,например),а не notification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не можете просто так взять и что-то повесить на рабочий стол устройства из своего приложения. Вам этого не даст система, дабы всякие приложения не засоряли всем чем им хочется рабочий стол.

Если вы хотите выводить какую-либо информацию для пользователя для этого есть `Notifications`. Вы можете выводить их из сервиса который будет запускать например `WorkManager`.

Если же вам кортит прям что-то показать на рабочем столе, то вы можете написать свой виджет, в котором будет нужная инфа. Но поставить ли его на рабочий стол решает только сам пользователь.

Никаких других способов уведомлять пользователя, а тем более через его рабочий стол Google вам не даст.